# Backbone and underscore does not show me the details of an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm loading a json file a list of objects and show them in a table. So far I have no problem, the problem is to show the object in detail. To retrieve the full version of the object back to make the request to the object / id server (which is actually a file) and recovery.

My model:

```
var RecursoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "assets/data/recursos", 

    idAttribute: 'id',
    defaults: {id: null, nome: '', tipo: ''}
});
```

In my code router.js detail function is as follows:

```
    detail : function(id) {

    var recurso = new RecursoModel({id:id});
    recurso.fetch();

    var recursoDetailTemplate = _.template(this.loadTemplate('recursoModelDetail'));
    this.recursoDetailModelView = new RecursoModelDetailView({
        template : recursoDetailTemplate,
        recurso : recurso
    });         
    this.changeView(this.recursoDetailModelView);
},
changeView : function(newView) {
    if(newView && this.currentView && newView != this.currentView) {
        this.currentView.hide();
        this.currentView = newView;
        this.currentView.render();
    } else if (newView) {
        this.currentView = newView;
        this.currentView.render();
    }
},
```

In the view controller:

```
var RecursoModelDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#contenido'),
    template : null,
    recurso : null,

    initialize : function(options) {
        this.template = options.template;
        this.recurso = options.recurso;
    },
    render : function() {
        console.log(this.recurso);
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.recurso.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    hide : function() {
        $(this.el).empty();
    }       
});
```

And the template:

```
<h3>Detail</h3>
<div>
    <p><label><%= id %></label></p>
    <p><label><%= nome %></label></p>
    <p><label><%= tipo %></label></p>   
</div>
```

My problem is that in firefox the first time I go into the detail tab does not show me any field, the second might. And with chrome or explorer never shows me anything. 
The request made to the server and retrieves the data well and the console.log I do in the render function the data is there but not shown. What could be the problem?

Comment: RecursoModelDetailView / render:
return this; --> return this.el;

Comment: I found the solution, I just had to add a listener in initializce sight, that updating the object's render correctly:

 initialize : function(options) {
  this.template = options.template;
  this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
 },

Thanks and regards.